# ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs with NMF and TF-IDF in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, tf-idf, nmf

I'm trying to estimate topics through [NMF](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.NMF.html) over a [TF-IDF](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer.html) decomposition.However when I run the following line:

```
nmf = NMF(n_components = dimension)
nmf_array = nmf.fit_transform(x_tfidf)
```

I got this error:

> ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs

But, when I search for Nans and infs inside the Tf-IDF  can't find any:

```
np.isinf(x_tfidf.data).any() #this return False
np.isnan(x_tfidf.data).any() #this also return False
```

The complete code is:

```
nltk.download('stopwords')
stop_words_sp = stopwords.words('spanish')
custom_stop_words = ["https", "citar", "www", "com", "youtube", "mil","ar", "hs"]
stop_words = custom_stop_words + stop_words_sp
count_vect = CountVectorizer(max_df = 0.9, min_df = 0.1, stop_words=stop_words, lowercase=True,analyzer=stemmed_words)
x_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(textos)

    # Genero matriz con valorizacion tf-idf
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
x_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(x_counts)
lda = NMF(n_components = 2)
lda_array = lda.fit_transform(x_tfidf)
```

Where the variable **textos** is an array of Spanish text without any empty string.

This is the complete trace error:

[image]

Comment: It's possible that somewhere along the way `x_tfidf` is processed to something with Infs or NaNs, and some function along the way catches that. For example, `np.log(np.zeros(5))` makes an array of Infs. Post the full stack trace, maybe that'll shed some light?

Comment: Since you use `x_tfidf` in `nmf.fit_transform` and `x_tfidf.data` in both `np.isinf` and `np.isnan`, it would also be useful to see what `x_tfidf` is.

Comment: I have update the post with the complete trace. This is what x_tfidf is:
<150x4691 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
 with 226514 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

Comment: Well, what you posted is probably useful too, but what I'm talking about is the error message printed to console when you hit an exception. It'll be headed by text like `Traceback (most recent call last):` and have the `ValueError ...` at the bottom.

Comment: Yes sorry, I have added an image with the complete trace error